# React native paper layout component as Box, Vstack, Hstack component in native base for grouping?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base, react-native-paper

I am creating react native expo app for Android, Ios and web. I have tried with native base ui components and it is easy to use. Best part was layouts like Vstack, HStack, Box.
But I want to use React Native paper, but it does not have any Flex layout related components.

Is there any other library that i should use with React Native paper for flex layout components?

Can I use React Native paper with Native base in production? Is it good practice?

Which UI library is best for react native expo which will give great look and feel , responsive design apis and supports all the IOS, Android and Web environments?

Comment: Anyone , Anybody from javascript community?

Comment: Anyone, any input for this?